# What is the arguments variable in the gtag snippet?

Tags: javascript, arguments, gtag.js

Open question. Looking at the Global site tag (gtag.js) snippet I don't really understand the use of the `arguments` variable.

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=GA_TRACKING_ID"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'GA_TRACKING_ID');
</script>
```

What does it mean exactly? What is the use of `dataLayer.push(arguments)` here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's nothing special to Analytics or gtag. It's just a standard Javascript object. It represent all the arguments passed to functions.

What analytics is doing here is just pushing into the dataLayer an object with all the parameters passed to the gtag tag. This doesn't mean you can simply remove the gtag function and use the dataLayer directly because once the gtag.js file is loaded it can replace the gtag function with a different function that keeps the same interface.

From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

> The `arguments` object is a local variable available within all
>   (non-arrow) functions. You can refer to a function's arguments within
>   the function by using the `arguments` object. This object contains an
>   entry for each argument passed to the function, the first entry's
>   index starting at 0. For example, if a function is passed three
>   arguments, you can refer to them as follows:
>
> ```
> arguments[0]
> arguments[1]
> arguments[2]
> ```

Comment: Yes, it pushes a single argument into the dataLayer, this one argument is an Array-like (meaning it looks like an Array but not quite) that includes all arguments passed to gtag() function.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Eduardo's answer, the `gtag()` function is defined in the gtag snippet without defined arguments. This is known as a [variadic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function#In_JavaScript).

The reason for this ambiguity in definition is that the `gtag()` function is used for a variety of purposes by the receiving dataLayer. You can see several use cases defined in [this Google Analytics help article](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9310895?hl=en#gtagjs-about&zippy=%2Cin-this-article) and read about the syntax and various command keywords in the [gtag.js API docs](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/gtagjs/reference).

From the gtag.js API docs:

> The Google tag (gtag.js) API consists of a single function, gtag(),
> with the following syntax:
>
> `gtag(<command>, <command parameters>);`
>
> `<command>` is one of the following commands:
>
> ```
> config
> get
> set
> event
> consent
> ```
>
> `<command parameters>` are the parameters you can pass to `gtag().`

When `gtag('config', 'Property_id')` is called, a Google property is being configured to receive page view data.

A different use of the gtag function occurs if the `'event'` command is passed.

For example:
`gtag('event', 'sign_up', { 'method': 'email' });`

This passes three parameters to the `gtag()` function, which is used for logging a sign up event in Google Analytics (or any other configured Google property on the page). From the GA help article:

> In this example, the "sign_up" parameter is the event name. The last parameter is an object that contains a set of event parameters. In this case, "method" is a parameter with a value of "email."

Here are some other examples, used for initiating Google Consent Mode:

```
  gtag("consent", "default", {
    ad_storage: "denied",
    analytics_storage: "denied",
    functionality_storage: "denied",
    personalization_storage: "denied",
    security_storage: "granted",
    wait_for_update: 500
  });

  gtag("set", "ads_data_redaction", true);
```

Due to the variety of use cases, the `gtag()` function defines no specific arguments, and uses the `arguments` object to push whatever parameters it finds to the dataLayer, which determines the appropriate use.